How to access metafield url (file_reference type)
In a Shopify "Customer account UI" extension, how can I access the url of a file_reference metafield?
Here is the folders/files structure in the extension folder:
|-- my-extension
|   |-- dist
|   |   |-- my-extension.js
|   |   |-- my-extension.js.map
|   |-- locales
|   |   |-- en.default.json
|   |-- src
|   |   |-- OrderStatusBlock.jsx (the file where I need to access the metafield url)
|   |-- package.json
|   |-- shopify.extension.toml

In OrderStatusBlock.jsx, I actually have:
import {
  Button,
  Card,
  InlineStack,
  reactExtension,
  useApi
} from "@shopify/ui-extensions-react/customer-account";

export default reactExtension(
  "customer-account.order-status.block.render",
  () => <OrderMetafields />
);

function OrderMetafields() {
  const { appMetafields } = useApi();
  const metafields = appMetafields.current;

  return (
    <>
      {metafields.length > 0
        ? <Card padding>
            <InlineStack gap>
              {metafields.map(metafield => (
                <Button
                  kind="primary"
                  key={metafield.metafield.value}
                >
                  {metafield.metafield.value}
                </Button>
              ))}
            </InlineStack>
          </Card>
        : ''}
    </>
  );
}

{metafield.metafield.value} return for example gid://shopify/GenericFile/1234567890 but how to access the URL, the name and the alternative text of a file_reference metafield (in order to download file)?
I have found the following code for liquid file but I don't even know if it can be done in a jsx file:
{% assign file_object = product.metafields.set_test.file.value %} <!-- replace the "set_test" part with your actual namespace and the "file" with the key -->
{% if file_object != blank %} 
 <div class = "file-reference">
  {% assign file_url = file_object.url %}
  {% assign file_name_with_shopify_extension = file_url | split: '/' | last %} <!-- parse the file name from the URL -->
  {% assign file_name = file_name_with_shopify_extension | split: '?' | first %} <!-- strip off the ?v=123456789 part of the file name -->
   <a href = "{{file_url}}" target="_blank">
    <div class = "file-name">
    {{ file_name }}
   </div>
  </a> 
 </div>
{% endif %}


The constant const metafields = appMetafields.current; return the list of metafields defined in the file shopify.extension.toml:
[[extensions.metafields]]
namespace = "custom"
key = "my_metafield"

The resulting object looks like:
console.log(metafields)
{
  metafield: {
    key: 'custom',
    namespace: 'my_metafield',
    value: '["gid://shopify/GenericFile/50044900344155"]',
    type: 'list.file_reference',
    valueType: 'json_string'
  },
  target: {
    id: '6234811498843',
    type: 'order'
  }
}

So you have the value (gid://shopify/GenericFile/50044900344155).
Now, to obtain the url and the alt, you have to query (Graphql - you have to add const { appMetafields, query } = useApi(); in you function) like so:
query (
  `query ($id: ID!) {
    node (id: $id) {
      ... on GenericFile {
        url
        alt
      }
    }
  }`,
  {
    variables: {
      id: "gid://shopify/GenericFile/50044900344155"
    }
  }
)
.then(({data}) => {
  console.log(data)
})
.catch(console.error);

And the data looks like:
node: {
  url: 'https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0001/0002/0003/f8iur5j988yq74w73459ep4kcj92quz9j.pdf?v=12345678',
  alt: 'my_file.pdf'
}

And you have the url and the alt of the file.
